# Bootstrap Modal Unexpected behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a LOGIN modal in the DROPDOWN menu.
The modal works fine upto some extent but -

1. it won't close when i click the RED Area
2. it does close when i click the GREEN Area

According to bootstrap docs the modal should close if i click anywhere outside the modal's area

here's the HTML

```
<header class = "header container-fluid  navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">

  <div class="container">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>

   <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">            
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Anime</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Manga</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>

    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >Log-In</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign-Up</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Watch Paralax</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</header><!-- end of header-->

<!--START of LOGIN MODAL-->

<div class = "container">
 <div class = "row">

  <div class=" col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8 modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-content" >
          <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                <h3>Login</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
              <form method="post" action='' name="login_form">
                <p><input type="text" class="span3" name="eid" id="email" placeholder="Email"></p>
                <p><input type="password" class="span3" name="passwd" placeholder="Password"></p>

                <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
                <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
                </p>
              </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">New here?
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Register Now, for FREE!!!</a>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>  
<!-- End of LOGIN MODAL -->
```

here's the pic showing areas
[image]

here's the pic showing modal
[image]

also, can someone explain what is this `class = span3` in `input` tag. I also want to make the `input` fields much wider with bootstrap alone.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why are you using offsets?

Comment: to center the modal

Comment: remove all those bootstrap classes from modal. By default modal is centered, there is  no need to use bs classes.

and if you inspect element you will see in footer before closing body tag a fade div is added, try increasing its z-index value

Comment: I think Bootstrap modal is already horizontally centered one..

Comment: by removing all those column classes , the modal takes up full width of the page but i dont want that :) @PratikDeshmukh

Comment: it should not take full width.
Anyways even if it takes full width you can write css rule to modal-dialog class like: .modal-dialog { width: 700px; margin: 0 auto; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

Remove all the grid bootstrap classes from modal. By default modal is centered, there is no need to use gird classes.

```
  <div class="container">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>

   <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">            
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Anime</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Manga</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>

    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >Log-In</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign-Up</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Watch Paralax</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</header><!-- end of header-->

<!--START of LOGIN MODAL-->


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                <h3>Login</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
              <form method="post" action='' name="login_form">
                <p><input type="text" class="span3" name="eid" id="email" placeholder="Email"></p>
                <p><input type="password" class="span3" name="passwd" placeholder="Password"></p>

                <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
                <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
                </p>
              </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">New here?
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Register Now, for FREE!!!</a>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>


<!-- End of LOGIN MODAL -->
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0tnbyLx1/

Comment: by removing .container .row and column classes the Modal is taking up full width of the page , but i dont want that :)

Comment: Sorry my mistake i forgot to add modal-dialog class, it works fine now but how can i determine its width according to my needs ? also in XS it takes up too much width